# Successful build in Maven still showing errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ejb-3.0

I'm having something quite peculiar here, my build is successful in maven when I type "mvn clean install" however once imported into Eclipse it's showing errors.

See for yourself:

[image: mvn clean install]

[image: Eclipse]

I guess exluding quartz from the `pom.xml solved the problem but I'd like to know why.

---

PS: Here is the `pom.xml` in case you want to see it:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.nantes.mpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyClient</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyClient</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nantes.mp</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyEjb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

###EDIT
As you can see quartz is here:
[image: quartz]

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree` in the command line and check where the quartz dependency comes from. If it is included transitive can you find it in your local maven repository?

Comment: the required version is inside my m2 :/

Comment: Oh you are right, I did not noticed :o sorry.
anyway, I did the maven dance^^ but in the end the problem was coming from the fact that m2e was using it's embeded version of maven and not mine.

Comment: I just noticed that you already found the reason and deleted my former comment about the different quartz versions.

Comment: faced the same problem and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932455/3724636    saved me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes I get these types of issues as well.

Generally, what worked best for me with Eclipse & Maven:

- Use the latest m2e Eclipse plugin
- Use Maven 3
- Make sure m2e uses the same Maven version as the one you're using on the command line (not the internal one)
- Import projects as Maven projects to generate the Eclipse project files

Comment: I'm quite embarassed xD m2e was not using my version of maven. it was set to "embedded".

I added the path to my maven installation and now it's working.

Answer (score 67):

Updating maven project after importing it has fixed this issue for me:

Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update project.

Comment: Thanks this helped me :)

Comment: Worked fine...!

Comment: In addition, after running maven-update-project on all projects, I sometimes have to then do a maven-update-project on our core library. Oddly, both steps are necessary in that order. The error I hit was "<a_class_name_here> cannot be resolved to a type" only it should be resolving just fine.

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!

Comment: @Eildosa This should probably be the answer to the question!

Comment: Sweet! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 10):

The other upvoted answers did not work for me using these versions:

- Eclipse Neon
- Maven 3
- m2e 1.7

This is what I had to do:

1. Delete the Eclipse project from Eclipse interface (do not delete project contents on disk)
2. Go to the project's root directory in a file explorer or terminal
3. Delete these files: `.classpath`, `.project`, and `.settings` directory
4. Back to Eclipse, File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects

Answer (score 8):

If you don't see any error in Eclipse project but it keeps showing the red icon on your project name. Try `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Then select all projects in Eclipse, Right click > Maven > Update projects

Hope it helps.

Comment: [**Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin (RETIRED)
Note: This plugin is retired. It is no longer maintained.**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

Answer (score 5):

You should try `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

And then make sure the `M2_REPO` variable is point to your local repository.

Comment: I'm using m2e so I don't need to do eclipse:eclipse

Comment: @Eildosa It seem you don't have quartz-1.5.2.jar.So add this dependency to your pom.xml, and try again.

Comment: If quartz is not in my pom.xml then eclipse is not suposed to look for it.
And if it was a transitive dependancy it would download it.

Comment: You saved my time. explored many options. But this was the ultimate one :)

Comment: Don't do eclipse:eclipse, it creates bunch of file in the build path.

Comment: [**Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin (RETIRED)
Note: This plugin is retired. It is no longer maintained.**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

Answer (score 5):

sometimes maven update nor all above works.
so check which import statement gives you error, then go particular lib file which is usually in c:user/ur-PC-NAME/.m2 get into package delete that .jar file.

then in eclipse, right click on project > maven > update maven.

Comment: I found the same thing was happening to me.  There was a .jar included as the scope "provided" and it was in my local repo but Eclipse wasn't detecting it.  I did a Maven "update project" and it didn't work still.  I was able to build the project from the command line maven.  
To resolve the issue, I did as you suggested, just deleted (or rename) the folder with the .jar in it in my maven local repo then update and build again and Eclipse picked it up.

Comment: @atom88, Yes some time eclipse is not able to pick it up. Good it fixed your problem.

Comment: @ShamanthRamesh, it worked, am using Eclipse 2020-09, please bear in mind to uncheck the `clean project` checkbox

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the m2e "maintained" eclipse project is out-of-sync with the actual project in POM (There are lots of reason for that).  Assume you have using m2e 0.8 or later, right click on the project, under Maven, there are two entries that are usually useful.  They are Update Dependencies and Update Project Configuration

Have a try on them, wait a while after u clicked that for eclipse to update the project and build.  Normally it solves similar problems.

Comment: didn't worked :/ I think I'm just going to exclude it (must be a transitive dependancy from jboss as client) because I tried everything...

Answer (score 3):

That often happens when the m2eclipse hasn't updated the build path to correspond to what a modified POM file says.  There's an entry in the Maven context menu to update the Configuration.

Comment: @Eildosa - Yea ... but it will probably work for other people.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

1. I just deleted project from Eclipse (not ticked checkbox to delete
   from project location).
2. Opened project as "Existing Maven Project" again.

and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my project was using a project specific Java Compiler setting set to Java 1.5.  Furthermore, the project facets were still referencing Java 1.5 when Maven, m2e, Eclipse general Java Compiler settings were all set to Java 1.8.

Comment: This is normally adjusted by "Update Project from Maven POM", but not always. It is good to see the JRE used in the library path to get alerted.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were also problems with Java build path like the following:
"Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment." Fixing this resolved compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You've a library (quartz-1.5.2.jar) that's reference to your m2 local repository which doesn't exist if you just remove the quartz from your build path and update your dependencies internally(in eclipse) that would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different/older version of JRE. In my case switching back to JRE7 from JRE8 eliminated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and Re-Import the project in eclipse (without deleting files of course).  Unlike other answers I have not looked into why this happens but it works.  poof - compilations errors be-gone

Comment: This STILL does not fix the issue for me, using Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 0):

It may help: After upgrading eclipse or changing it or something like, old eclipse specific files (.classpath, .project, and .settings) may not be compatible to the new version of eclipse. So you may have to re generate this eclipse specific files using Maven. So try this in your eclipse project root

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: [**Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin (RETIRED)
Note: This plugin is retired. It is no longer maintained.**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, eclipse starts to show all errors after I changed some versions of dependencies in pom.xml, however the command line mvn clean install build successfully

1. I deleted folders of the dependencies I changed manually from the .m2 repositories (in my case everything under org.apache.beam), because I also has corrupted dependency issues.
2. mvn clean build the project, this downloaded the dependencies again
3. right click project: maven -> update project
4. delete the project from eclipse (but not from disk) and reimport (this actually left me with 1 error still, then i delete and reimported again)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse> Project (Menu) > Clean... > Select project to clean

This also removes invalid errors from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For me Right click on the project --> Maven --> Update project with the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkmarked worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some times, eclipse's validation causing these errors.
You can disable them by going to Menu>window>preferences>validation and uncheck suspend all validators or disable them one by one for builds.
E.G, every time You build the project eclipse does not validate your files and does not show up those errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Delete the Eclipse project from Eclipse interface (do not delete
   project contents on disk)
2. Go to the project's root directory in a
   file explorer or terminal
3. Delete these files: .classpath, .project,
   and .settings directory
4. Back to Eclipse, File -> Import... -> Maven
   -> Existing Maven projects

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, I deleted the project from my workspace (not on disk), opened the project folder and deleted the files `.project`, `.classpath` and the folder named `.settings`.
Now goto eclipse again, import the same project again and viola my error is gone!