# Gradle project in eclipse builds fine but java files show compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

This is my first gradle project. I am using [Buildship eclipse plugin](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) for gradle. In my **build.gradle** file, I have below plugins applied -

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
```

All the relevant dependencies are defined as compile as below -

```
.
.
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateVer}")
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVer}")
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:${hibernateValVer}")

compile ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVer}")
compile ("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVer}")
.
.
```

The project builds and runs successfully using tomcatRun command as well. But the eclipse is showing compilation errors on my imports in java files, saying that the dependencies can not be resolved.

I tried Project->Clean and then refresh, but still stuck. What can i do to remove these compilation errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you project build path- java version, libraries, etc and the path specified in the gradle scripts are different

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing the project from workspace and importing it again as a gradle project fixed the issue for me. Maybe somewhere down the path I have done something that has removed the "gradle" nature of the project.

Comment: I just created a new gradle project and followed a tutorial. Errors on eclipse but compiles with gradlew build. I followed your method deleting project and reimport, it worked fine. But what causes this massacre is the big question.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on your `Project-> Goto Gradle-> Refresh Gradle Project`. Eclipse would pick the jars downloaded by gradle now.

Comment: There isn't a "Goto Gradle" option in the menu

Comment: @crashspringfield you should have menu option when having buildship plugin installed into your eclipse. Can't say for newer versions of this, but atleast that's the way it was for me when I answered it.

Comment: @crashspringfield, Right click on your project in Package Explorer -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after successful build, Go to Package Explorer (not Project Explorer) -> Press ctrl+A (select all) -> right click & refresh.
I think it will help to resolve all the dependencies and all the errors in eclipse will be gone. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had to remove the following files from my web client project under `.settings`:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs
```

Then I also had to manually modify `.settings/gradle.prefs` to properly define the following:

```
projectPath (was ":" changed to ":projectNameClient")
connection_project_dir  (points to the EAR project path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete project from STS and import as Gradle - that fixed the issue.