# How to migrate the artifacts of a maven project which has a parent artifact into Azure Artifacts?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, maven-2, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to migrate the artifacts of  a maven project from Sonatype Nexus to Azure Artifacts and I'm following the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59946185/20781864).

So it's basically

1. mvn clean install: Creates a local copy of the artifacts.
2. Change the repository and distribution management URL and point to the destination Azure feed url.
3. mvn deploy: Deploys the artifacts into Azure feed.

This must work. But the project that I'm working on has a parent, which is provided to us externally and is not in maven central. That parent is not getting deployed and is missing from Azure Artifact feed and is resulting in an error.

Sample pom.xml

```
<project xmlns....>
<parent>
  <groupId>parent.pom..     
  ..
</parent>
<groupId>main.project...     
<name>project..     
<version>x.x..    
<packaging>pom..  
....    
....
</project>
```

Getting error on trying to build the project from Azure Artifact.

```
C:/...MainProject> mvn clean install        
...       
...
[ERROR][ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs     
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for main.project...: Could not transfer the artifact parent.pom
```

Tried to create a small project with only parent pom as dependency and tried to upload it Azure Artifact feed.

But a similar error is being thrown up.

Comment: Have you tried the following steps?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please check if there is a proxy in your internet.

And try to delete the .m2 local Directory and run `mvn clean install` again to check if it works.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476367/project-build-error-non-resolvable-parent-pom).