# Maven builds multi module project succesfully, Eclipse shows errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext, xtend

*Note: this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11030422/3083982), but the answers there did not work for me.*

I have an odd problem: using Maven in the command line, my build is succesful, but imported in Eclipse it still shows errors. In particular, I'm trying to build the open-source [rosetta-dsl](https://github.com/REGnosys/rosetta-dsl) project, which is a multi module Maven project containing Xtext and Xtend files.

Running `mvn clean install` ends with the following result:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for com.regnosys.rosetta.parent 0.0.0.master:
[INFO]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.parent ........................ SUCCESS [  0.282 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.lib ........................... SUCCESS [ 17.832 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta ............................... SUCCESS [02:22 min]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.target ........................ SUCCESS [  0.114 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.blueprints .................... SUCCESS [  1.168 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.tests ......................... SUCCESS [ 40.176 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.ide ........................... SUCCESS [  3.613 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.ui ............................ SUCCESS [  3.721 s]
[INFO] com.regnosys.rosetta.ui.tests ...................... SUCCESS [ 21.185 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-06T14:59:53+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Eclipse shows 40 errors, including:

```
Bundle 'net.bytebuddy.byte-buddy' cannot be resolved    MANIFEST.MF /com.regnosys.rosetta.lib/META-INF  line 16 Plug-in Problem
Bundle 'org.apache.commons.lang3' cannot be resolved    MANIFEST.MF /com.regnosys.rosetta/META-INF  line 24 Plug-in Problem
Bundle 'org.mockito' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /com.regnosys.rosetta.lib/META-INF  line 15 Plug-in Problem
Bundle 'org.mockito' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/META-INF    line 20 Plug-in Problem
Bundle 'org.objenesis' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /com.regnosys.rosetta.lib/META-INF  line 17 Plug-in Problem
Bundle org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved  build.properties    /com.regnosys.rosetta   line 21 Plug-in Problem
org.mockito.Mockito cannot be resolved to a type.   DocReferenceTest.xtend  /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/docrefs line: 19 /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/docrefs/DocReferenceTest.xtend Xtend Problem
The method mock(Class<Attribute>) is undefined  RosettaExpressionJavaGeneratorTest.xtend    /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/qualify line: 282 /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/qualify/RosettaExpressionJavaGeneratorTest.xtend  Xtend Problem
The method when(Object) is undefined    RosettaExpressionJavaGeneratorTest.xtend    /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/qualify line: 269 /com.regnosys.rosetta.tests/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/generator/java/qualify/RosettaExpressionJavaGeneratorTest.xtend  Xtend Problem
```

What I have tried:

- Right-clicking on the project and running Maven > Update Project... (which is [the top anwser of the similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649212/3083982))
- Deleting the project and reimporting it as a Maven project
- Updating Maven, the m2e Eclipse plugin and Eclipse to the latest version
- Running `mvn clean`, Project > Clean, closing and reopening the project, ... and rebuilding

but the problem persists, and after fruitlessly searching for a solution for the last three days, I'm not sure how to continue.

I don't know how or why this project behaves differently from the one in the linked question, so here are more details:

- `> mvn --version`

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Users\Thesis\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

- JDK compliance in Eclipse is set to 11
- I'm running Eclipse DSL Tools version 2021-06 (4.20.0)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: did you load the target file inside `com.regnosys.rosetta.target` as your target platform from within eclipse. Open the file. There should be a button in the top right.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Good call. That solved a big part of the problem. Now it seems I have one problem remaining: `com.regnosys.rosetta.types.RosettaOperators` still shows an error `null - See error log for details`. In the error log, there are two exceptions with the same message: `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant  - Error during compilation of 'platform:/resource/com.regnosys.rosetta/src/com/regnosys/rosetta/types/RosettaOperators.xtend'.`. Any idea on this?

Comment: there should be an entry in error log view showing details

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Yes, I found it. `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.resource.BatchLinkableResourceStorageWritable.logIfResourceMismatch(BatchLinkableResourceStorageWritable.java:144) [...]`. Could this be a bug with xtext?

Comment: is it happening consistently. or goes it away if you touch the file?
https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/issues/695

Comment: @ChristianDietrich The problem seems to go away then. When cleaning and rebuilding the project however, the problem gets picked up again, but I can 'fix' it once more by touching it. It seems the issue you linked describes the problem, so I won't file another one. If you want, you can post an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plugin-development, Eclipse needs to have a target platform configured. You can find a target file in the `com.regnosys.rosetta.target` project.
If you open that file with the target editor you will find a button in the top right that allows you to set the file as active target platform in your eclipse.